# Can I appy same rule for group of fields in Laravel5 request validation?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, optimization, laravel-5

I am using laravel request form validation and I want to apply same rule for more than one field.Is it possible for in any simple way? or need to write code for individually.
My validation rule given below.

```
  protected $rules = [
    'phone' => ['max:11'],
    'work_phone' => ['max:11'],
    'mobile' => ['max:11'],
];
```

Can I group these filed in to single rule?

Comment: How exactly do you use those rules? From what I know you should have a `rules()` method returning them. May I see a bit more of your code?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#form-request-validation  I am using form request validation.It is in laravel 5 but not in old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some things inside the `rules()` method:

```
public function rules(){
    $phoneRules = ['max:11'];
    return [
        'phone' => $phoneRules,
        'work_phone' => $phoneRules,
        'mobile' => $phoneRules
    ]
}
```

Or:

```
public function rules(){
    $fields = ['phone', 'work_phone', 'mobile'];
    return array_fill_keys($fields, ['max:11']);
}
```

In case you have other attributes to validate with other rules you'd need something like this:

```
public function rules(){
    $fields = ['phone', 'work_phone', 'mobile'];
    $phoneRules = array_fill_keys($fields, ['max:11']);
    $otherRules = [
        'foo' => 'required',
        'bar' => 'min:30'
    ]
    return array_merge($phoneRules, $otherRules);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the **Custom Validation Rules** section of the documentation, which precisely address this problem : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules